# How to combine two indicator columns in Python / Pandas where the logic depends on the ordering of the rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to create a column that selects all dates between each entry and exit.
Each entry is only paired with one exit.

- So when the window function sees an entry i.e. 1/4/2019 it turns on
  '1' until it sees an exit 1/6/2019. The next day it turns off '0'.
- It ignores all exits (i.e. 1/6/2019) until it sees the next entry
  i.e. 1/9/2019 and then it starts recording '1''s until the next exit
  i.e. 1/11/2019.

The dates are order from most recent date to first date.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Entry':[0,0,0,1,0 ,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                    'Exit':[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]},
                   index = pd.date_range('1/1/2019',periods = 12))
df1 = df.iloc[::-1]
df1
```

> The base table looks like this:

[image]

I want to create an additional column called windows that looks exactly like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Btw; it is not very clear what you want, i don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick (I know this might not be the most pythonic way, but hopefully you will all give me points for legibility):

```
# First I sort so I don't have to work backwards
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)

# Generate Window and then iteratively fill it
df1['Window'] = 0
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row.Entry == 1:
        # Once found, fill all intermediate values as 1 and break.
        # Nothing happens if no exit found.
        for subindex, subrow in df1.loc[index:].iterrows():
            if subrow.Exit == 1:
                df1.loc[index:subindex,'Window'] = 1
                break

# Sort back to the index order you wanted      
df1.sort_index(inplace=True,ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thank you this is very clear and gives the answer I need. . Because the answer is very clear I can apply it easily to the complex real world validation problem I'm facing.

Comment: I was thinking about this more last night, and you should beware of what happens when an entry and an exit happen at the same time. In this case, my code will set the window = 1. If this is what you want, great, if not then you need to write an additional condition to deal with this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic in the window function is not very clear to me. But it seems what you need is to apply a function row-wise which can store some memory (last entry status or whatever). A good way is to define a callable class, as below. Note you need to sort the df in increasing date order before you can use this.

```
class WindowFunc(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_status):
        self.status = initial_status

    def __call__(self, row, enter_col, exit_col):
        enter_val = row[enter_col]
        exit_val = row[exit_col]

        if self.status == 0 and enter_val == 1 and exit_val != 1:
            self.status = 1
            return 1
        elif self.status == 1 and enter_val != 1 and exit_val == 1:
            current_status = self.status
            self.status = 0
            return current_status
        else:
            return self.status

window_fn = WindowFunc(0)    
df['window'] = np.apply_along_axis(window_fn, 1, df, 0, 1)
```

The instance stores the status and persists the memory of it across rows. You can update the logic in the class to suite your needs.

Comment: interesting. gives me a little diff output though, but worth an effort.

Comment: Thank you for this effort. I do get the right answer when I apply your solution if I add .iloc[::-1]  afterward. I choose the second solution as what I am going to use right now because I don't understand classes well enough to defend an answer with a class method.